# Bluetooth Low Energy: gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor() returns null

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor, characteristics

I have a problem with getting characteristic's descriptor, it always returns null.
There is a chunck of my code:

```
public static final String CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public final static UUID tmp_uuid_1 = UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
```

...

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(tmp_uuid_1);
descriptor.setValue(true ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : new byte[]{0x00, 0x00});
```

I tried this on Nexus 6 with Android 5.1 and Nokia X2 DS with OS 2.0 like Android 4.3, and have a similar error.

Waiting for answers )
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uuid for notification descriptor is "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" instead of the "00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" in your code.

Comment: I arrived here because `getDescriptor` is returning `null`. However, I am already using the correct UUID :(

Comment: @me-- Please ask this as a separate question. It's hard to discuss that in comments.